# Minimum jQuery version for using jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am planning to use jqGrid for one my existing projects.I really liked column header grouping option.Currently i am using jQuery 1.5.2 version.So can this version be used with latest version of jqGrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [jqGrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asystem) (section *System Requirements*) to work with jqGrid you'll need the following:

> - Any modern web browser: Mozilla Firefox, Safari, Google Chrome, Opera, Microsoft Internet Explorer
> - **jQuery library, version 1.3 or later**
> - Your choice of a jQuery UI theme
> - The jqGrid plugin

**Reference:**

- http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:system

Comment: ..Thanks.. I missed that jqGrid wiki page :-)